# issue when running sequence library in UVM

Tags: uvm

when I'm running a sequence library in UVM, I got such error: "[SEQLIB/START] Starting sequence library top_random_seq_lib_v1 in unknown phase: 10 iterations in mode UVM_SEQ_LIB_RANDC". I'm confused why there is message on "unknown phase" because I start this sequence library in main phase. It seems this sequence library doesn't work correct. Can anybody help me to identify where could be the problem? thanks.

My code is something like this:

```
    class digit_top_base_random_test2 extends digit_top_base test;
        ......
        top_random_seq_lib_v1      m_seq_master;  // this is my sequence library for master
        top_random_seq_lib_v1      m_seq_slave;  // this is my sequence library for slave
        base_sequence              m_base_seq_master;
        base_sequence              m_base_seq_slave;

        ........


        virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
            ....
            m_seq_master=top_random_seq_lib_v1::type_id::create("m_seq_master");    
            m_seq_slave=top_random_seq_lib_v1::type_id::create("m_seq_slave");
        endfunction

        virtual task configure_phase(uvm_phase phase);
            super.configure_phase(phase);

            m_seq_master.selection_mode = UVM_SEQ_LIB_RANDC;
            m_seq_master.min_random_count=1;
            m_seq_master.max_random_count=5;
            m_seq_master.add_typewide_sequence(m_base_seq_master.get_type());

            m_seq_slave.selection_mode = UVM_SEQ_LIB_RAND;
            m_seq_slave.min_random_count=1;
            m_seq_slave.max_random_count=5;
            m_seq_slave.add_typewide_sequence(m_base_seq_slave.get_type());

            m_seq_master.init_sequence_library();
            m_seq_slave.init_sequence_library();
        endtask

        ........

        virtual task main_phase(uvm_phase phase);
            super.main_phase(phase);
            phase.raise_objection(this);
            m_seq_master.start(m_digit_top_env.m_agent_master.m_seqr0);
            m_seq_slave.start(m_digit_top_env.m_agent_slave.m_seqr0);
            phase.drop_objection(this);
        endtask
    endclass
```

Answer (score -1):

After several day's debug, finally I found the answer: I typed wrong code which result in wrong sequencer allocation. That wrong code doesn't show in my post. After correct that mistake the code works fine. Thanks for those people who have reviewed this post.